# How can I apply ng-style dynamically if ng-class is true?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class, ng-style

```
.test{color:red;background:blue;}
.test.selected {
position:relative;  left: 100px; padding:10px; background:green;
}

<div ng-style="myStyle" ng-class="{select: x.selected}" ng-click="select(x)" ng-repeat="x in myData" class="test"></div>


$scope.select = function (text) {   
    text.selected = true;
};

$scope.myStyle = {
    'color':'white',
    'font-weight':'bold'
}
```

When the div element has className "selected" by using condition true, how can I add  'myStyle' in ng-style as well. How to apply inline ng-style dynamically if ng-class condition is true? Here below I am able to see in debugger in inline with classNames added. Now I have the condition true and I can see the classname "selected" to it(class="test ng-scope selected"), All I want is an inline ng-style="myStyle" to be added when its true.

```
<div ng-class="{select: x.selected}" ng-click="select(x)" class="test ng-scope selected" ng-repeat="x in myData">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like to this.

```
<div ng-style="x.selected && {'color':'white','font-weight':'bold'}"  
    ng-click="select(x)" ng-repeat="x in myData" ></div>
```

***Demo***

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', ['angular.filter']);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
  {
    "id": 100,
    "value": "2452"
  },
  {
    "id": 100,
    "value": "2458"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "2457"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "2459"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "value": "2460"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "value": "3458"
  }
];

$scope.select = function(x){
  x.selected = !x.selected;
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="aCtrl">
<div ng-style="x.selected && {'color':'red','font-weight':'bold'}"  
    ng-click="select(x)" ng-repeat="x in data" >
      {{x.value}}
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use ng-style for selected item, you can do this with ng-class(**Recommended**)

Style

```
.selected {
 'color':'white',
 'font-weight':'bold'
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-class="{'selected': x.selected}" ng-click="select(x)" ng-repeat="x in myData" ></div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.select = function(x){
  x.selected = !x.selected;
}
```

Comment: I'm using inline style because I want to assign the inline style with dynamic values like (screen.width/2, document.body.clientHeight/4) which I cant to assign through css.